# Как присвоить часть строки другой строке?

Tags: java, строки

Допустим у меня есть строка:

```
String str = "зелёный куст";
```

И строка `String d;`

Как мне сделать так, чтобы программа проверила наличие слова "зелёный" в строке str, а затем, если это слово есть, присвоила его строке d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = "зеленый куст";
String strZel = "зеленый";
String d;
if(str.contains(strZel)) d=strZel;
```

Метод `str.contains(str2)` проверяет наличие в строке str подстроки str2 и возвращает `true`, если она есть и `false` , если нет